# ¿Señal post_delete para un atributo del modelo con Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo un modelo `Foto`, en el cual quiero ejecutar algo, cuando el campo `imagen` se modifique o se limpie, usando `Signals` en `Django`

Este es el modelo:

```
class Foto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    imagen = VersatileImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%D/',
                                 null=True, blank=True)
```

Y mas adelante tengo un `@receiver` con la señal `post_delete`:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Foto)
def delete_Curso_imagen(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes ExampleImageModel image renditions on post_delete.
    """
    instance.imagen.delete_all_created_images()
```

El problema es que el `@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Foto)` envía una señal cuando el objeto se elimina. Lo que deseo es que se envié una señal cuando el atributo `imagen` del objeto se modifique o se limpie. No se como hacer eso.

Comment: Podrías trabajar con una señal `post_save`, que se envía cuando se guarda un objeto, por lo cual es fácil interpretar que se ha modificado dicho objeto.

Comment: Cabe recalcar que no existen señales de campos, o señales que se envíen cuando un campo en especifico es modificado, eliminado, etc. Solo señales enviadas por modelos.

Comment: El problema de usar usa señal ```post_save``` es que se eliminaran las imágenes creadas con el VersatileImageField cada vez que modifique algo de una instancia del modelo.

Comment: No te entendi bien, explicame detalladamente.

Comment: El para el atributo ```imagen``` estoy usando un VersatileImageField, para poder hacer operaciones a imágenes en mis templates (crop, resize, etc) y que tiene todas las funcionalidades de un ImageField. Pero para cada operación con una imagen del modelo, se crea una imagen como resultado. Ya anteriormente usaba ```django_cleanup``` para que cuando cambie una imagen o archivo, el archivo anterior se borre del disco. El metodo ```delete_Curso_imagen``` sirve en parte para eso, pero ```django_cleanup``` no limpia las imágenes generadas por ```VersatileImageField```.

Comment: OK, entonces cuando el usuario suba otra imagen quieres que la imagen que subió anteriormente se borre, verdad?

Comment: Eso ya funciona con ```django_cleanup```, quiero borrar las imágenes que crea VersatileImageField, cada vez que se hacer un crop o algo a la imagen principal. VersatileImageField crea una carpeta a parte donde se contiene todas las imágenes modificadas, por lo que con el paso del tiempo se van acumulando imágenes ahí.

Comment: Ok, ese campo `VersatileImageField` tiene el método `delete()`? Si es posible dame un link a la documentación de como funciona, estoy buscándola y no la encuentro.

Comment: La documentacion de ```VersatileImageField``` de la version que estoy usando es https://django-versatileimagefield.readthedocs.io/en/1.10/overview.html, y si, como puedes ver en el metodo ```delete_Curso_imagen()``` está ```instance.imagen.delete_all_created_images()``` que elimina todas las imagenes creadas para esa instancia, pero hace eso solo con la señal ```post_delete``` del modelo.

Comment: Ok ya publique mi respuesta mira si así ya se resolvió tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu comentario de querer eliminar las imágenes creadas por cada operación ejecutada sobre el campo `VersatileImageField`, seria así:

```
def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    # Obtenemos la instancia anterior
    old_instance = Foto.objects.get(pk = instance.pk)

    # Eliminamos las imagenes de la instancia
    old_instance.imagen.delete_all_created_images()

    # Retornamos el path en donde se guardara la nueva imagen
    return 'photos/%Y/%m/%D/' + filename

class Foto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    imagen = VersatileImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
```

No estoy seguro si funcionara ya que no se como funciona el campo `VersatileImageField`, si puede enviar mas parámetros de los esperados, etc

En dado caso que se envíen mas parámetros de los esperados, añade los parámetros `*args` y `**kwargs` a la función `custom_upload_to`.